# How do I save a user id as a relation of the User model?

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to insert a user_id as a 'foreign key' into the question table using `Auth::user()->id`.

My model:

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    //saves post
    public function saveQuestion(buildQuestion $buildQuestion, $userId){
        $buildQuestion->user_id = $userId;
        return $this->user()->save($buildQuestion);
    }
```

My controller:

```
public function submitQuestion(Request $request,buildQuestion $buildQuestion){

        $answers = new buildQuestion($request->all());


        if (Auth::user()){

            $buildQuestion->saveQuestion($answers, Auth::user()->id);

        }else if(Auth::guest()){
            abort (403, 'Not Logged In');

        }
    }
```

I don't think I'm supposed to be passing the `buildQuestion` as a parameter in the model.

I'm getting this error when i submit the form: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Comment: You should avoid defining the save function within the model. It should go to the controller. Use the model to define relations, mutators etc, but not Controller tasks

Answer (score 0):

```
Class BuildQuestion{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
...

  Class User{
    public function buildQuestion(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\BuildQuestion');
    }
...
```

controller

```
public function submitQuestion(Request $request){

    $answers = new buildQuestion($request->all());


    if (Auth::user()){

        Auth::user()->buildQuestion()->create($answers);

    }elseif(Auth::guest()){
    //suggestion redirect to login page
    //return redirect('/login');
        abort (403, 'Not Logged In');

    }
}
```